# Extract file path from android Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to extract file-path from received Intent.ACTION_SEND? I'm trying to list my android app in "Share via" list. To do so, I've the manifest like this:

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/*" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now I select my app from the "Share-via" list. Is it possible to get the full file path from the received intent (for all file types)? This is what I've done so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TextView output=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    String action = intent.getAction(); 
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) { 
        String s = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); 
        output.setText(s); //output: a TextView that holds the URL 
    }
}
```

I've seen many solutions for this, but most of them are restricted to image sharing. Any help please?

Comment: see [Receiving an ACTION_SEND intent from the Gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632966/receiving-an-action-send-intent-from-the-gallery) maybe help you

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen the solution already. It works fine for image sharing from Gallery but not for any file type (where sharing options are available, say my file manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

you can get the file path

```
        _file = getIntent().getData().toString();
    if (_file.startsWith("file:///"))
        _file = _file.substring(7);
```

to get all mime types you can use

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```

If you want to analyse how other apps handle intends you can use the free android app [intentintercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) to analyse them

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!